Session Manual Ad Content returns as numbers instead of specified/generated string
We have created URLs with specific UTMs as identifiers, among them are unique Ad Content parameter.
However, some of the Ad content hits we see in GA4 returns as numbers instead of our specifically generated UTM Content parameter.
Example URL:
www.website.com/landing-page?utm_campaign=campaign-a-2024&utm_content=content-abc2024&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email
but in GA4 or Looker Studio, we see this:

Is there any reason why is this happening? and are there workarounds?

Show an example, pls

thank you! i have edited with examples. it totally went over my head

I carried out some tests and was unable to replicate the exception. You should see if indeed all the UTMs you have used have the value you expect or if during their construction and use that content was wrong from the start. This is the most likely hypothesis from experience

Got it. thank you for responding Michele!

by the way @MichelePisani, may i know how did you replicate or run tests for cases like these?

I tried it on one of my website by inserting your utm's on a url, did some tests and none came up as abnormal
